# Where can I find documentation for this?

Tags: php

Where can I find documentation for the following code?

```
$a = .01 * rand(0, 100) >= .5; //I don't need doc for this line, its for generating a random boolean!
$b = "it was true!";
$c = "it was false!";

echo "Guess what, " . ( $a ? $b : $c ); // I need documentation for how this works!
```

http://viper-7.com/H8upUh

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. I mean this:
var ? var : var

Comment: I know the example is inefficient, but it's just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and it's a way to consolidate a simple `if/else` expression.

From the docs:

```
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, will tick it in 9 mins.